# How to manually create tags using Bootstrap Tags Input

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) for introducing tagging mechanism in my project. So far I can easily load predefined `tags` using `add` method as described in the documentation, But I am unable to create tags manually. Say I type some text and press `space` or `comma` button then a new tag should be created, Just like we add tags while writing `Stack overflow` question. Is it possible to add this behaviour, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/Nodws/bootstrap4-tagsinput